# Error in seting up spfx 1.7 with angular 7

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, angular2

Hi I am setting up a SPFX 1.7 project with Angular 7 using the sample which is done with previous version.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OgEqWtouuU

https://winsmarts.com/use-spfx-with-angular-cli-3747c306244b

https://github.com/maliksahil/SPFxAngularCLI

I am getting below error while builing the application

[image]

Comment: Have you tried scaffolding with [generator-spfx](https://pnp.github.io/generator-spfx/), which supports angular?